# Selecting a child tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want from among the boxes that I have placed in the code below; Select the box whose z-index is equal to 3 and make its background red and the title white to distinguish it from other boxes.

html:

```
<ul>
        <li class="post1">
            <div class="content">
                <h4 class="title">title post1</h4>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="post2">
            <div class="content">
                <h4 class="title">title post2</h4>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="post3">
            <div class="content">
                <h4 class="title">title post3</h4>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="post4">
            <div class="content">
                <h4 class="title">title post4</h4>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li class="post5">
            <div class="content">
                <h4 class="title">title post5</h4>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

For this purpose, I wrote a script code that does not work properly.
That is, the background of the box becomes red, but the color of the title does not change:

script:

```
$("li").each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).css("z-index") == 3) {
      $(this).css("background-color","red");
       $(this).children(".title").css("color","white");
    }
  });
```

Comment: `.children()` only matches immediate child nodes; you're looking for a grandchild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may be with children, try using find.

```
$(this).find(".title").css("color","white");
```